# Add column header to Google Sheets with python gdata.spreadsheets?

Tags: python, google-sheets, gdata

I'm using the python gdata API for google spreadsheets with gauth.  I can easily insert a row and fill only certain columns but I can't figure out how to add a new column.

I connect to the spreadsheet with this:

```
import json, gdata.gauth, gdata.spreadsheets.client
from oauth2client.client import Signed JwtAssertionCredentials

def connect():
        json_key = json.load(open('jsonfile.json'))
        scope = ['https://spreadsheets.google.com/feeds']
        credentials = SignedJwtAssertionCredentials(json_key['client_email'], json_key['private_key'], scope)
        client = gdata.spreadsheets.client.SpreadsheetsClient()
auth2token.authorize(client)



        entry = gdata.spreadsheets.data.ListEntry()


        key = "spreadsheetkey"
        return entry, client, key
```

And then to add a row with certain columns filled, I use:

```
entry, client, key = connect()
entry.set_value('column_name',cell_value)
entry.set_value('column2_name',cell_value)
client.add_list_entry(entry,key,'od6')
```

This works as long as the column already exsists.  Is there a way to create a new column with a specific name?